# how to leave from chrome pdf viewer page in kios mode

Tags: google-chrome, kiosk

i'm using chrome kiosk mode.
When i open pdf it's open in chrome pdf viewer but i cant leave this page wihout keyboard. so user stucking on this page. how to fix this? maybe there is a way to make button "home" at top of site in chrome?

Comment: How do viewers interact with this kiosk? Is it a touchscreen? A mouth/touchpad?

Comment: this is touchscreen device.

Comment: I have the same question.